# How to calculate max values between two rows of Particular Column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

> I am trying to calculate max and min values between High and Low from index 9:00 to 9:30, the problem I am facing is my loop including second row of previous iteration each time.you can see in the output , in the second iteration it calculated the max/min between second and third row of High and Low Column. However it should be the max/min of third and fourth row.
>   below is the code

```
i=0
while i<6:
    for _, g in points.groupby(np.arange(len(points)) // 2):
            print(i)
            print(g)
            Max_High_val= points.iloc[i:i+2,:].loc[:,'High'].max()
            print("Max 'Max High' value Between 9:00 and 9:30 is :",Max_High_val)
            Min_Low_val= points.iloc[i:i+2,:].loc[:,'Low'].min()
            print("Max 'Max Low' value Between 9:00 and 3:30 is :",Min_Low_val)
            i+=1
```

> **Output**

```
0
                              Open    High    Close      Low    return
Datetime                                                              
2020-01-03 09:00:00-05:00  3227.25  3229.5  3221.25  3220.25 -0.100604
2020-01-03 09:30:00-05:00  3221.00  3239.5  3237.25  3220.75 -0.193663
Max 'Max High' value Between 9:00 and 9:30 is : 3239.5
Min 'Min Low' value Between 9:00 and 3:30 is : 3220.25
1
                             Open     High   Close      Low    return
Datetime                                                             
2020-01-06 09:00:00-05:00  3218.0  3219.75  3214.5  3213.75  0.000000
2020-01-06 09:30:00-05:00  3214.5  3227.25  3225.5  3213.25 -0.108763
Max 'Max High' value Between 9:00 and 9:30 is : 3239.5
Max 'Max Low' value Between 9:00 and 3:30 is : 3213.75
```

> **Sample Data**

```
                   Open     High    Close      Low    return
Datetime                                                               
2020-01-03 09:00:00-05:00  3227.25  3229.50  3221.25  3220.25 -0.100604
2020-01-03 09:30:00-05:00  3221.00  3239.50  3237.25  3220.75 -0.193663
2020-01-06 09:00:00-05:00  3218.00  3219.75  3214.50  3213.75  0.000000
2020-01-06 09:30:00-05:00  3214.50  3227.25  3225.50  3213.25 -0.108763
2020-01-07 09:00:00-05:00  3239.50  3241.25  3239.50  3238.00 -0.154107
2020-01-07 09:30:00-05:00  3239.50  3242.25  3235.00  3231.75  0.000000
2020-01-08 09:00:00-05:00  3239.75  3241.50  3239.00  3238.75 -0.138707
2020-01-08 09:30:00-05:00  3239.00  3248.00  3246.50  3236.00 -0.023150
2020-01-09 09:00:00-05:00  3270.75  3272.00  3271.00  3269.25  0.022936
2020-01-09 09:30:00-05:00  3270.75  3274.00  3269.25  3265.50  0.000000
2020-01-10 09:00:00-05:00  3281.75  3283.50  3282.00  3280.75  0.007618
2020-01-10 09:30:00-05:00  3282.75  3283.50  3280.75  3274.75  0.030472
```

Comment: can you post a sample of your data, i think a better way would be to do a `.loc` and then `groupby` `df.loc[df['Datetime'] <= '01-01-01 09:30:00'].groupby...`

Comment: Hi, I have edit the post and added the data

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take a moment to read about how to post pandas questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: is the date immaterial here, do you only care about time?

Comment: Yeah my only focus is time, however my problem is not with time time , problem is why I am getting 3239.5 in second iteration, its a max between second and third row however it should calculate the max between 3rd and 4th row

Answer (score 0):

```
df['max'] = df.High.rolling(2).max()
df['min'] = df.Low.rolling(2).min()
```

This should work.

If you want to drop the NaN you can use the following command

```
df.dropna(inplace=True)
```